# Why does this code not terminate

Tags: scala

This code :

```
object SpeedTest extends Application{

  val l = (1 to 50).toList.par

  println("par done")
  var counter = 0;

  for(e <- l){
      counter + 1
  }

  println("Finished")

}
```

never terminates. If I remove `counter + 1` then it does terminate. What is causing this code to hang?  Is there deadlock occurring in the count increment ?

Update 1 :

Updating the code to use main method instead of extending Application :

```
object SpeedTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    SpeedTest.doInPar
  }

  def doInPar = {
    val l = (1 to 50).toList.par

    println("par done")
    var counter = 0;

    for (e <- l) {
      counter + 1
    }

    println("Finished")

  }

}
```

This terminates, so possibly extending Application is having an adverse effect.

Update 2 :

My setup :

```
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627
Java version : 1.6
Scala version : 2.10.4
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with scala but am interested so forgive the dumb question.  I dont see how this is multithreaded? (how can there be a deadlock?)  I'm assuming thats a for each loop? In scala, can `e` and counter have any interaction?

Comment: Range doesnt have toList ? so not sure how is it working.

Comment: This works for me. What is your set-up?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas `.par` turns the list into a [parallel collection](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html).

Comment: @ggovan ive edited question with setup

Comment: @blue-sky I don't know that not extending App solves the problem, so much as removing the code into a function. If you extend app and merely call the function, it should be the same. I was going to suggest using delayedInit, but that was deprecated in 2.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben Reich stated, this is possibly a REPL bug, and I think it is one that is happening because of a sort of "recursion deadlock". I can get this to work if I move the counter variable into another object as below:

```
object Somes{ var counter = 0}

object SpeedTest{
  val l = (1 to 7).toList.par

  println("par done")
  var counter = 0;
  for(e <- l){
      println("loop start for " + e)
      Somes.counter + 1
      println("loop done for " + e)
  }
  println("Finished")
}
```

If you start using the `SpeedTest.counter`, you will see that it runs to the `counter` access and stalls. My guess is that the object hasn't fully completed, so trying to access the internal variable deadlocks as it is still building itself.

In fact, this is strengthened by adding a `lazy val f = ...` to the for loop assignment and referencing it after initial construction.

Comment: thanks, ive also posted an update to question which also causes code to terminate